# How to implement Haskell *Maybe* construct in D?

Tags: haskell, d, construct

I want to implement `Maybe` from Haskell in D, just for the hell of it.
This is what I've got so far, but it's not that great.  Any ideas how to improve it?

```
class Maybe(a = int){ }  //problem 1: works only with ints

class Just(alias a) : Maybe!(typeof(a)){ }

class Nothing : Maybe!(){ }


Maybe!int doSomething(in int k){

  if(k < 10)
    return new Just!3;  //problem 2: can't say 'Just!k'
  else
    return new Nothing;
}
```

Haskell Maybe definition:

```
data  Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [std.typecons.Nullable](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#Nullable). It's not exactly the same as `Maybe` in Haskell, but it's a type which optionally holds a value of whatever type it's instantiated with. So, effectively, it's like Haskell's `Maybe`, though syntactically, it's a bit different. The source is [here](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/typecons.d) if you want to look at it.

Comment: I looked at the source code at it looks similar to what Justin has posted.  If it's in Phobos, why bother reinventing the wheel?  I'll use Nullable, :)

Comment: True, not exactly like Haskell `Maybe`, but close enough.

Comment: Whether it suits your pruposes depends on what you're trying to do. In general, I'd encourage you to use `Nullable`, because it's in the standard library, but if your main purpose is simply to learn (as your question implies might be the case), then that's different.

Answer (score 5):

what if you use this

```
class Maybe(T){ }  

class Just(T) : Maybe!(T){ 
T t;
this(T t){
this.t = t;
}
}
class Nothing : Maybe!(){ }


Maybe!int doSomething(in int k){

  if(k < 10)
    return new Just!int(3); 
  else
    return new Nothing;
}
```

personally I'd use tagged union and structs though (and `enforce` it's a Just when getting the value)

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used the Maybe library, but something like this seems to fit the bill:

```
import std.stdio;

struct Maybe(T)
{
    private {
        bool isNothing = true;
        T value;
    }

    void opAssign(T val)
    {
        isNothing = false;
        value = val;
    }

    void opAssign(Maybe!T val)
    {
        isNothing = val.isNothing;
        value = val.value;
    }

    T get() @property
    {
        if (!isNothing)
            return value;
        else
            throw new Exception("This is nothing!");
    }

    bool hasValue() @property
    {
        return !isNothing;
    }
}

Maybe!int doSomething(in int k)
{
    Maybe!int ret;

    if (k < 10)
        ret = 3;
    return ret;     
}

void main()
{
    auto retVal = doSomething(5);
    assert(retVal.hasValue);
    writeln(retVal.get);

    retVal = doSomething(15);
    assert(!retVal.hasValue);
    writeln(retVal.hasValue);
}
```

With some creative operator overloading, the Maybe struct could behave quite naturally. Additionally, I've templated the Maybe struct, so it can be used with any type.